# (C#) How can I access a property of the parent class?

Tags: c#, class, object, parent

I want to access a property of my master object.
Here, after instantiating the class City, I want to know the country this city belongs to.

```
public class Country
{
    public string NameOfCountry { get; set; }
    public List<City> Cities { get; set; }
    public Country()
    {
        NameOfCountry = "USA";
    }
}
public class City
{
    public City()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello. I live in " + NameOfCountry);
        //Error: The name 'NameOfCountry' does not exist in the current context
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to give it the reference to the parent.There are many ways to do this. It is a design decision: pass it in the constructor, do not expose the list of cities directly and create a custom `Add(city)` where you `city.Country = this` Otherwise have it stored somewhere else. Depends on you.

Comment: You can't. The City class has no concept of a Country. If you want to be able to interrogate an object, you need to have a reference to that object. Your City class has no reference to any Country object. Instead of using a standard List, you'd need a custom collection that held a reference to the Country. It would then pass that reference to the City when it was added and clear it in the City when it was removed.

Comment: I think there are design flaws.
You are actually use 2 distinct classes that are not linked to each others.
I'd follow jmcihinney suggestion or I would rather change the overall design. You could also have a City class where country is a property of the same.

Comment: Adding to @MicheleRava , City should logically inherit from Country therefore City would know which Country it belongs to, rather than Country having a list of Cities.